# Does ReflectionProperty::setAccessible make the property forever accessible?

Tags: php, reflection

I would like to have a private property in a class, and be able to set it with another, via a ReflectionClass.

I know that if I create ReflectionProperties of the class' properties, I can set them to accessible, and then set their values.

However, if I set the property to accessible, does it become accessible everywhere (like a public property), or is it just in the context of the ReflectionProperty?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you have a private property you need to set elsewhere, why not just provide a public setter for it?

Comment: This could be useful when writing tests..

Comment: @liquorvicar It's not for a typical private property - it should be set by one thing, in a certain place only, and it may happen after construction. Weston's comment applies also.

Comment: @johnnietheblack If it should be set by one thing maybe it should be a property of that thing? As for testing, there are other ways to skin that cat. That's why I asked what you're trying to achieve. IMHO reflection is a little bit dirty/magical and should be a last resort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will only be accessible through the `ReflectionProperty::getValue()` and `ReflectionProperty::setValue()`, so the original class and all its instances will not have their visibility changed.

Example:

```
    <?php

    class MyClass {
       public function __construct() { $this->priv = 42; }
       private $priv;
    }

    $a = new MyClass();

    $ref = new ReflectionClass("MyClass");

    $prop = $ref->getProperty("priv");
    $prop->setAccessible(TRUE);

    echo "priv: " . $prop->getValue($a) . "\n";  // OK!

    echo $a->priv;                               // <-- error
    ?>
```